# Using ggplot2 stat_summary with geom col to create distinct sum bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a barplot with a summary bar `Total` showing the sum of two groups: `Pulses, Total` and `Soybeans`.

I know it is possible to achieve it by pre-processing the data to get the sum as a summary by group, I am looking for a `stat_summary` solution. I am not very familiar with `stat_summary()`, any advice is welcome as I might have overlooked something...

**Reprex:**

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L
), Item = c("Soybeans", "Soybeans", "Soybeans", "Pulses, Total", 
"Pulses, Total", "Pulses, Total"), Value = c(884688L, 829166L, 
960640L, 2219455L, 2354696L, 2683772L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

What I've tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = Value)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = sum,
    geom = "col",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.95),
    aes(fill = "Total")
  ) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.95),
    aes(fill = Item)
  )
```

[image]

As you can see, the `Total` bar does not appear as a 3rd distinct bar. Is it possible to achieve this while keeping the two others and without pre-processing the data?

**Expected output:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Value = sum(Value), Item = "Total") %>% 
  bind_rows(., df) %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = Year, y = Value, fill = Item)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Note: `geom_col` doesn't give you totals of `Soybeans` / `Pulses, Total` because you have multiple obs of each group per `Year`.

Comment: Hm, I pretty sure that there is a solution, but it will be be much more complicated as your  own `tidyverse` approach.

Comment: @MartinC.Arnold thanks for your comment, it was not intented, I think the dataset  is right now (I forgot a filter when I made it from the true data...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `position_nudge(x = ..)` on the total column, and set the barwidth accordingly, for example:

```
library(ggplot2)

barwidth = 0.3
n = length(unique(df$Item))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = Value)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = sum,
    geom = "col",
    position = position_nudge(x = -1.5*barwidth),
    aes(fill = "Total"),
    width = barwidth
  ) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge(),
    aes(fill = Item),
    width= barwidth * n
  )
```

[image]